# Uploading News attachment from file in database D2L Valence API

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I'm having some issue with **uploading file attachments for News** in Valence API. I'm using PHP and when I try to make a post request, the action never gets completed. I'm running it on command line so I have to kill the process to terminate the program.

My file data and details(Name, Type and Size) are stored in the database and I'm using just **one call to post everything** i.e. the News in JSON Format and the file attachments. I'm using the following format for the post message (As mentioned in the API docs):

Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=e9e1c17c958e2a89a192bf5d3f7d1ffd
Content-Length: 46538

--e9e1c17c958e2a89a192bf5d3f7d1ffd
Content-Type: application/json

{"Title":"Some News","Body":{"Text":"This </span>is a very </span>colorful title</span>","Html":"This </span>is a very </span>colorful title</span>"},"StartDate":"2013-11-06T05:00:00.000Z","EndDate":"2013-11-30T05:00:00.000Z","IsGlobal":false,"IsPublished":true,"ShowOnlyInCourseOfferings":false}

--e9e1c17c958e2a89a192bf5d3f7d1ffd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FC.png"; filename="FC.png"

Content-Type: image/png

{}
--e9e1c17c958e2a89a192bf5d3f7d1ffd--

I **can't see the file content** due to encoding I guess. I'm calculating the content-length in this message as: **string length of the JSON data + filesize in bytes**.

My very speicific question is that can one post files from the database directly or it's recommended to write the file to the disk first then try posting. I would also appreciate if someone can point me to an example online where there's a pre-existing sample code using PHP for this.

One more thing. If I do not include the file-size in bytes for the content-length, then it works fine except for the file attachment. It is 29 bytes in size and when I click on it, it opens with corrupt data error.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I was doing wrong. Needed to UTF encode the file document data before using json_encode on it. The data was getting lost during json_encode as it does not understands special characters. Code snippet:

```
$fileData = array(
    'FileName' => $attachment->getDocumentFilename(),
    'FileType' => $attachment->getDocumentFileType(),
    'FileSize' => $attachment->getDocumentSizeByte(),
    'FileData' => utf8_encode($attachment->getDocument())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Content Length` of the HTTP request must be the length (byte-count) of the *entire* HTTP body. This means the JSON structure's size, the number of bytes in the file-stream, *as well as* the length of all surrounding body-part headers/separators and whitespace.

There's no particular requirement about the data store where your uploaded file data comes from. Essentially, you're forming an HTTP request with multiple parts in the Body: the first part must be the JSON structure (of media type `application/json`); the second part should be the bytes for the "file", and the media type for that body part set appropriately `image/png` or whatever) -- whether you gather that byte stream from a database, or from a file, doesn't really matter.

Comment: I just corrected the Content-Length property of my post request. I'm still having the same issues with posting News with attachments. I'm not sure if I need to check something on my server configuration.

Comment: It also looks like you don't have new lines and carriage returns in the right spaces. Note that your example really should look like the file upload examples in the docs (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/fileupload.html) and conform to the referred-to multiparty body RFCs... They're sensitive about treatment of white space.

Comment: Well, made those identical. Still having the same issue. One more thing that I noticed this time is that I'm not including headers in the post option(**CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS**) but only in headers option(**CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER**). In the link that you posted, it shows the headers as part of the request. Do I need to do that again for the post option in cURL.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed comment response. I'm not sure; I don't use the cURL library; I believe that others who've used it with PHP have run into various issues that make it tricky to use, especially with data uploads (POSTs and PUTs).

Comment: Hi, although this is an old thread but I'm having some tough time with file uploads. Could you please point me to some sample code where I can see the code for uploading a file for News, Dropbox, etc.?

Comment: The 'D2LValence-Util' package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/D2LValence-Util) contains a relatively simple (and incomplete, and in places buggy) client service abstraction layer I built on top of the auth package, and the Valence LF API. Look at the `_simple_upload()` internal method inside `service.py`, as well as its use inside the various dropbox routes, locker routes, and content routes; news uses a slightly different scheme for upload (multipart/mixed), so `create_news_item_for_orgunit()` has its own upload code in it.